# Magento open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp) is not within the allowed path(s):

Tags: php, magento

i'm having some trouble about uploading image on Magento CMS in all page/product.
I've enabled erro log and i'll report it to check.
NOTE: Only for post now,  I have sobstitute my address domain with "mydomain.com". Only for sample.

> [Sun Feb 02 15:02:14 2014] [error] [client 146.105.28.41] client
>   denied by server configuration:
>   /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/app/etc/local.xml
>
> [Sun Feb 02 15:02:18 2014] [error] [client 146.105.28.41] client
>   denied by server configuration:
>   /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/app/etc/local.xml
>
> [Sun Feb 02 15:02:36 2014] [warn] [client 151.67.115.48] mod_fcgid:
>   stderr: PHP Warning:  Unknown: open_basedir restriction in effect.
>   File(/tmp) is not within the allowed path(s):
>   (/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear) in
>   Unknown on line 0
>
> [Sun Feb 02 15:02:36 2014] [warn] [client 151.67.115.48] mod_fcgid:
>   stderr: PHP Warning:  File upload error - unable to create a temporary
>   file in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add an open_basedir exemption for /tmp, turn open_basedir off entirely, or change the php temp directory to something within /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com.

1. I recommend the first.
2. I've read reports (With no explanation) that you should do the second.
3. You can do the 3rd from within the Apache config:

   ```
   <Directory /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/>
       php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/temp
   </Directory>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Answers here did not work for me:

- an open_basedir exception for /tmp is usually not the best solution, because it means that users have access to other users' tmp files (possible security issue)
- open_basedir is usually active for a reason, switching it off entirely might be a security issue
- the problem still occured after modifying the upload_tmp_dir

For me, the magento installation worked after I set the php.ini value `sys_temp_dir` to a value within the open_basedir directory.

To be safe, I checked all tmp paths displayed in `phpinfo()` and changed them like this:

`<Directory /var/www/myvirtualhost>
php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/www/myvirtualhost/tmp
php_admin_value soap.wsdl_cache_dir /var/www/myvirtualhost/tmp
php_admin_value opcache.lockfile_path /var/www/myvirtualhost/tmp
php_admin_value sys_temp_dir /var/www/myvirtualhost/tmp
</Directory>`